# IntelliJ IDEA JUnit5 Tags Run Configuration Error Module Not Specified

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5

I'm trying to use tags in JUnit5 to exclude some deliberately slow running tests. However, I have an `Error: Module not specified`, yet I cannot find anywhere to select a module. Excluding the tags section, nothing else has changed from the standard all in package options. The `use classpath of module` option is not selectable.

[image]

This is a pain because it brings up the run configuration dialogue box every time I run my tests. How do I specify the module?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Is it possible to provide sample project example?

Comment: `Use classpath of module` is it not what you're looking for?

Comment: `Use classpath of module` is greyed out and cannot be selected.

Comment: IDE version is Community 2018.2.6. I'm not sure if I can provide a sample project, I'll have to have a play and put one together. I can probably link to this one on GitHub later today.